# How do you hard code a file name with a variable path name?

Tags: batch-file

First, I would like to apologize because I have little programming knowledge and I have my fingers crossed that I am not wasting your time.

My problem is that I have a series of folders which house image files as well as all their auxiliary files. The image files and all their auxiliary files have the same name. There can be many image files (and their corresponding auxiliary files) in one folder.

What I need to do is zip the image file, it's auxiliary files, a disclaimer file and a readme file all together. This is where it gets tricky. There is only one disclaimer file for the entire lot so it sits in the root directory. The part that is giving me grief is the readme. There is only one readme file per folder and it's always named 'readme.txt'. There is no individual readme.txt for each image - just one per image folder. That one readme.txt, however, needs to go in the zip file for all of the images in its folder.

The code I have recursively goes through each folder gets each image, it's auxiliary files, the disclaimer, and zips them all together. What I cannot seem to get it to do is find the readme file in each folder and have it zip that in as well.

I believe the problem is I cannot figure out how to have the path name a variable and end with hard coded `readme.txt`.

**Edit:** The directory structure is as follows:

- **folder A**

  - disclaimer.txt
  - **folder B**

    - **folder C**

      - a.tfw
      - a.tif
      - a.aux.xml
      - a.xml
      - b.tfw
      - b.tif
      - b.aux.xml
      - b.xml
      - c.tfw
      - c.tif
      - c.aux.xml
      - c.xml
      - readme.txt
      - **folder D**

        - d.tfw
        - d.tif
        - d.aux.xml
        - d.xml
        - e.tfw
        - e.tif
        - e.aux.xml
        - e.xml
        - f.tfw
        - f.tif
        - f.aux.xml
        - f.xml
        - readme.txt

Here's my code:

```
@echo off

for /r %%F in (*.tfw) DO "C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7Z.exe" a "%%F.zip" "%%~fF" "%%~dpnF.tif"  "%%~dpnF.xml" "%%~dpnF.tif.xml" "%%~dpnF.aux.xml" "readme.txt" "C:\temp\disclaimer.txt"

for /r %%a in (*) do (
    for %%f in ("%%~na") do (
        ren %%~a %%~nf%%~xa
    )
)

XCOPY *.zip d:\new_aerials /s
```

Comment: If you added "%%~dpFreadme.txt" at the end of the first FOR, wouldn't that work? Could you provide an example of your directory structure and file names?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use this commented batch code for this task:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Search for file disclaimer.txt and exit the batch processing with
rem an error message if this file cannot be found in directory tree
rem of the current directory.

for /R %%I in (disclaimer.txt*) do (
    set "DisclaimerFile=%%~fI"
    goto FindReadme
)
set "FileName=disclaimer.txt"
goto ErrorMessage

rem Search for first file readme.txt and exit the batch processing
rem with an error message if not a least 1 readme file can be found
rem in directory tree of the current directory.

:FindReadme
for /R %%I in (readme.txt*) do (
    set "ReadmeFile=%%~fI"
    goto CompressFiles
)
set "FileName=readme.txt"

:ErrorMessage
echo Could not find the file "%FileName%" in directory
echo.
echo    %CD%
echo.
echo or any subdirectory of this directory.
echo.
endlocal
pause
goto :EOF

rem Compress into a ZIP file each *.tfw file found in any directory of
rem the directory tree of current directory with all files with same
rem name in same directory as the *.tfw file with the disclaimer.txt
rem found before and the readme file in same directory as the *.tfw
rem file or last found readme.txt. The ZIP file is created in same
rem directory as the *.tfw file with same name as the *.tfw file.

rem Last copy all *.zip files with duplicating the directory tree
rem to the directory D:\new_aerials

:CompressFiles
for /R %%I in (*.tfw) do (
    if exist "%%~dpIreadme.txt" set "ReadmeFile=%%~dpIreadme.txt"
    "%ProgramFiles%\7-Zip\7z.exe" a -tzip -x^^!*.zip -mx=9 -mtc=off -y "%%~dpnI.zip" "%%~dpnI.*" "!ReadmeFile!" "%DisclaimerFile%" >nul
)
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe *.zip D:\new_aerials\ /Q /R /S /Y >nul
endlocal
```

Please look into 7-Zip help file `7zip.chm` for details about the used 7-Zip switches. The exclamation mark `!` needs to be escaped here with `^^` because delayed expansion is enabled while running the compression.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `echo /?`
- `endlocal /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `if /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `setlocal /?`
- `xcopy /?`

And see also the Microsoft article [Using command redirection operators](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490982.aspx) for redirection of messages output by `7z.exe` and `xcopy.exe` to handle **STDOUT** to the device **NUL** to hide those output messages.